# I have 3 dates, need to find the number of days on each side of the middle date.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime

I'm working on an rails application that builds budgets for our clients. They enter a date range to the budget, for this example, 1/1/2014 to 12/31/2014 - a full year. They can also enter the date that the new raises would go into effect. We need to calculate what a budget would look like for an employee at their old wages, and the new wages.

So I've been testing a couple of scenarios with the following code:

```
def number_of_days_at_old_wages
  if adjusted_date != scenario.start_date
    (scenario.start_date.to_time.to_i..adjusted_date.to_time.to_i).step(86400).count
   else
    0
   end
end

def number_of_days_at_new_wages
  if adjusted_date != scenario.start_date
    (adjusted_date.to_time.to_i..scenario.end_date.to_time.to_i).step(86400).count
  else
    number_of_days_in_scenario
  end
end

def number_of_days_in_scenario
  (scenario.start_date.to_time.to_i..scenario.end_date.to_time.to_i).step(86400).count
end
```

'adjusted date' is the date that they enter when the new raises into effect.

Here's what this produces:

1. **Adjusted Date of 1/1/2014**

   - `number_of_days_at_old_wages == 0`
   - `number_of_days_at_new_wages == 365`
2. **Adjusted Date of 7/2/2014** (supposed 'middle of the year')

   - `number_of_days_at_old_wages == 182`
   - `number_of_days_at_new_wages == 183 (total of 365)`
3. **Adjusted Date of 1/5/2014**

   - `number_of_days_at_old_wages == 5`
   - `number_of_days_at_new_wages == 361 (total of 366)`

Obviously, I'm counting adjusted_date in the range twice, but I'm just at a loss on how to get this to work. 3 dates, need to find the number of dates on each side of the middle date. Any help would really help me get on with my day.

Comment: Simple. if the adjust pay goes into effect on (say) Feb 10th, then your "pay at old rate" range should be Jan 1 -> Feb 9th. Subtract a day from the "old" range, to compenstate for counting the day-of-raise twice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I should have mentioned I did think of this, but after subtracting a day:
 2. **Adjusted Date of 7/2/2014** (supposed 'middle of the year') 
   - `number_of_days_at_old_wages == 181`
   - `number_of_days_at_new_wages == 183 (total of 364)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def number_of_days_at_old_wages
  (adjusted_date - scenario.start_date).to_i
end

def number_of_days_at_new_wages
  (scenario.end_date - adjusted_date + 1).to_i
end

def number_of_days_in_scenario
  (scenario.end_date - scenario.start_date + 1).to_i
end
```

`(...).to_i` it's needed because `Date` subtraction returns a `Rational`

The `+1` is because those ranges include the start date

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working. We used to have something similar (subtracting dates, then using to_i), but I think the key was the +1s, which, is quite obvious now.